# Identity for anonymous user in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to be able to identify unique anonymous users so I may store some information in the database for that user. Something like a guest shopping cart.

I don't particularly want to use session, because I like the easy fail-over between servers if I keep building with a no-session-data approach.

Is there any way in either spring security or generic spring to get an identity token that I can use to identify particular anonymous users (primary key)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know alternative way in Spring Security or Spring in general but why you just get SessionId from `session.getId()`

> Returns a string containing the unique identifier assigned to this
>   session. The identifier is assigned by the servlet container and is
>   implementation dependent.Returns:a string specifying the identifier
>   assigned to this session

and save this sessionId to db. This way you not fail between server, you already save it to database.

Comment: Would session id be consistent between servers? So if I have two servers, and I set up sticky sessions, if a server fails, will the guest users from that server still keep the same session id when they're redirected to the remaining server?

Comment: @RichardG You are right at that case Tomcat return different sessionId to user.

Comment: Let us say you deployed your application to multiple app servers.  Your expectation now is that no matter which server a user's request hits, that request must get fulfilled according to the identity of the user.  This means, the server-side set up is completely transparent to the user.  This would also mean that the session is replicated across all the servers.  If you are not storing anything in the session explicitly, the session itself is a very tiny object so having it on multiple machines is not such an issue.  Therefore, you should be able to reliably use the session ID on any server.

Comment: So it sounds like  the only way to fail-over a guest account is to synchronise the session data in a cluster and rely on the session identity. I had hoped to make the application stateless, but it doesn't sound like there's an easy (and secure) way to generate an anonymous user cookie - something like Websphere's LTPA token...

Comment: I would suggest you to check Spring-session -> with that, you could persist the session scoped object to a caching/storage layer, which means you avoid making the application server perform the session replication.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue in for spring security 4. Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48194411/5728095) just inject into the filter correspond services look up to user's info.