# Customize Spring Security for trusted space

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

Service works after gateway in trusted space (gateWay verifies OAuth token and gives to the service only unique user ID other case it redirects to authenticate service).

I want use spring security in the service to be able validate permissions for userId.

So I've added `CustomUserDetailsService`

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private ContextSsoActiveProfileIdProvider contextSsoActiveProfileIdProvider;
    @Autowired
    private GrantedAuthorityService grantedAuthorityService;

    @Override
    public User loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // verify it with authentication service, but there is not token, userId only, so trust to gateway service.
        return new User(
                String.valueOf(contextSsoActiveProfileIdProvider.getSsoActiveProfileId()),
                "authenticatedWithGateWay",
                grantedAuthorityService.getGrantedAuthoritiesForCurrentUser()
        );
    }
}
```

Where *contextSsoActiveProfileIdProvider.getSsoActiveProfileId()* returns uniqueUserId and *grantedAuthorityService.getGrantedAuthoritiesForCurrentUser()* returns authorities.

The service starts in trusted zone so I have configured security in next way:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

I need provide free access for all users (without triggering login offer) for all URIs (`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();`) but it seems suppressed triggering handlers for next annotations `@PreAuthorize`, `@PreFilter`, `@PostAuthorize` and `@PostFilter`.

I suppose I mistook here with `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();` or with other configuration part.

More issue symptoms:

- `CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(..)` is never called;
- On REST API part `@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser` is null
- On REST API part `Principal principal` is null also

Comment: You must overwrite another method for loadByUserName to be called. The method is " @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {}"

Comment: This information is not enough, because configure of this method doesn't solve my issue without additional tricks. There are a lot of elements to research via spring security sources (to find out information about additional tricks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trusted space issue has similar solution to anonymous user identification (I've done this conclusion when I was working on it.)

### Short answer

Trusted space does not need authorization, but no *UserDetailsService* will be called, because of using only `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider` and `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` by default. It is good enough implement custom filter based on `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` overriding `createAuthentication` and replace default (`AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`) with custom one (`CustomAnonymousAuthenticationFilter`):

```
    @Configuration
    public static class NoAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter identifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.anonymous().authenticationFilter(identifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter);
            http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }
```

### Full answer

I found out that **CustomUserDetailsService** will never be called if user is not authorized. Continuing research pay attention on the **AnonymousAuthenticationFilter** which is responsible for creating anonymous user info. So in the very and purpose is to replace the  **AnonymousAuthenticationFilter** with my **IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter** where some methods should be overridden:

```
@Component
public class IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter extends AnonymousAuthenticationFilter {
    public static final String KEY_IDENTIFIABLE_ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION_FILTER
            = "Key.IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter";
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private GrantedAuthorityService grantedAuthorityService;
    private AuthenticationDetailsSource authenticationDetailsSource
            = new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource();

    public IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter() {
        this(KEY_IDENTIFIABLE_ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION_FILTER);
    }

    public IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter(String key) {
        super(key);
    }

    @Override
    protected Authentication createAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        AnonymousAuthenticationToken auth = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(
                KEY_IDENTIFIABLE_ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION_FILTER,
                userDetailsService.loadCurrentUser(request),
                grantedAuthorityService.getGrantedAuthoritiesForCurrentUser());
        auth.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
        return auth;
    }
}
```

to inject it into configuration

```
@Configuration
public class IdentifyAnonymousConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter identifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().authenticationFilter(identifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter);
    // ... some other configurations
    }
}
```

Now it seems much better, because *identifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter* is injected in **AnonymousConfigurer**. Pay your attention to your configurations based on `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. If you have few ones and one of them will not set *customAnonymousAuthenticationFilter* but configured earlier than *custom..* you'll get default instance of *AnonymousAuthenticationFilter* (configured in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` by default):

```
  protected final HttpSecurity getHttp() throws Exception {
      //...
      http
        .csrf().and()
        .addFilter(new WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter())
        .exceptionHandling().and()
        .headers().and()
        .sessionManagement().and()
        .securityContext().and()
        .requestCache().and()
        .anonymous().and()
      // ...
```

I would not care about it if application fixed, but **AnonymousAuthenticationFilter** called earlier than **IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter**. And *doFilter* puts into **SecurityContextHolder** `incorrect` Authentication.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(this.createAuthentication((HttpServletRequest)req));
        if(this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() + "'");
        }
    } else if(this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        this.logger.debug("SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: '" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() + "'");
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

So when next time *doFilter* is called for **IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter** it does not replace the `Authentication` because of condition `if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)` (see method before).

As result would be really good to provide configuration where fix for `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration using magic annotation **@Order** to manage configuration loading order.

### Warning

Or someone could think - add `doFilter` overriding in **IdentifiableAnonymousAuthenticationFilter** without condition (it is **hack**):

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(createAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) req));
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '"
                    + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() + "'");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

It is not acceptable if you need spring security with handling authorized/authenticated user but in some cases it is enough.

### P.S.

Some parts of the solution could be improved but I hope that idea is clear in general.